# jwplayer 6: how to dynamically load file, using javascript api?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I am trying to migrate from jw5 to jw6.

In jw5, I was able to dynamically load a video:

```
myplayer.load({file: 'myfile.mov', image: 'mysplash.jpg'});
```

This does not work in jw6.  I have spent a lot of time looking through the online documentation, and have not found any references to `.load`.  I am beginning to fear this is no longer supported. The document '[migrating from jw5 to jw6](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28834/migrating-from-jw5-to-jw6)' has this cryptic comment:

> The jwplayer().setup() call is now the only valid method to embed media

Does this mean it is no longer possible to dynamically load the player with a new file, for example in response to a click event, using the javascript api?  Must all files be specified in a playlist, during the initial player setup?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should still be able to use the load() call in JW6. http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference

load(playlist)
    Loads a new playlist into the player. The playlist parameter is required and can be either an array with playlist items or a string that points to the location of an RSS feed.

If you are having issues getting load() to work in JW6, please provide an example for debugging, thanks.

Comment: It is working for me now.  Thanks for your help! I have run into another problem though, which I posted here: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/javascript-interaction/30379

Answer (score 6):

I got this problem too and I found what is the issue.

Instead of JWP5, JWP6 does not work with the `load()` function if no media is specified upon setup.

If I used this code:

```
jwplayer("container").setup({
    width: 640,
    height: 480
});
```

after that, the `load()` function is not working.

The workaround is to specify initial some existing dummy media file:

```
jwplayer("container").setup({
    width: 640,
    height: 480,
    file: '/some/summy/file.mp4'
});
```

after that JavaScript function `load()` can load new media.

This is the BUG !!!

Comment: Hi, I am still seeing the same behavior with latest version of jwPlayer. Does this mean I have to always supply a dummy video on setup?

Comment: @JD. Yep, I belive this is still an issue. If you don't need the Flash fallback and can rely solely on HTML5 you can get away with specifying someing like ".mp3" as the dummy source, but that gives me the "no playable sources found" error with the Flash payer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post however i would like to give an example of what i would do (JWplayer6)

```
var playerInstance = undefined;
button.onclick = function(newData){
    if (playerInstance === undefined){
        playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
        playerInstance.setup({
            width: 640,
            height: 480,
            file: newData
        });
    } else {
        playerInstance.load(newData);
    }
};
```

Dummy content loads the player with data the user may not want, and the bonus of pre-loading the player on the page offers only a slight advantage to loading on a request. (waiting for the player js to execute)